# Drop image into a web browser programmatically C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have an image object and need to drop it in a certain position in a web browser control

```
foreach (Image img in selectedImages)
{
    int xLocation = input.GetBoundingClientRect().Location.X;
    int yLocation = input.GetBoundingClientRect().Location.Y;

    // what I should do next ?
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Are you trying to do a drag and drop operation programmatically with images? Or are you trying to load the images in the web browser control? Or are you just trying to overlay the images on the web browser control?

Comment: Keep in mind that the contents of the web browser control are JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. It uses the IE7 rendering engine and as such it doesn't understand .Net objects directly beyond the same way every winforms control does.

Comment: trying to do a drag and drop operation programmatically with images